# Excel sheet as return value for a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, excel

Is it possible?

Would you advise a better way?

Do you know an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this. Set the `Content-Type` header equal to `application/vnd.ms-excel` and then set a `Content-Disposition` to something similar to this: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename_here.xls"` and then return your Excel data.